# SCI-TX doesnt work properly (Serial communication)

Tags: serial, communication, interface, simulink

Part Number: TMS320F280025C,

Other Parts Discussed in Thread: LAUNCHXL-F280025C, C2000WARE,

I have a simulink model for a power electronics project and i want to see detailed data using SCI-TX port in simulink. For this, i have created 2 codes, one is for code generation and the other one is for watching the data. Both of the codes work without a problem in LAUNCHXL-F280025C. The default pins are GPIO28 and GPIO29 for TX and RX, and when i want to change these pins, using the hardware switch at the launchpad also creates no problem and i am able to also use GPIO16 and GPIO17 pins.

However, using the TMS320F280025CPNSR (this processor is used in my project card), i cannot get the data interface to work in any ways. The pins are selected as GPIO16 and GPIO17 in project card. In summary, with the launchpad, i am able to see the data on sci pins, but the same codes do not work for the control card (i change the build configurations to TI F28002x.) I have tried lots of methods, i tried GPIO2 and GPIO3 pins instead, didnt work. I even tried to change the value for OUTPUTXBAR7 to SCI-TX(6) but this didnt work either.

Even this simple code where i read adc values and send it to serial pin does not send any data to my SCI-TX pin.(The codes themselves work but i do not see any data in model.) The only difference is that the FTDI we use is XDS100, but i have seen this card being used without any problem in other projects ( for example 49c.) The pins do not have a physical connection problem, as we tested them with a multimeter. I ran the sample sci code and my normal code on controlcard. The signals without noise came from controlcard, and i was able to see these signals using the TX pin on hardware.(GPIO16)

However, it seems that the data is not being sent to pc, as i was not able to see any data in my interface model and putty application. The signal with noise comes from launchpad, but i am able to correctly read the data from my interface model.  I don't have any ideas left, any suggestions?